# Django sign up with facebook return an error

Tags: django-facebook

*as Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.**

> im using http://127.0.0.1:8000 
>   so here  is how i have set my facebook
>   domain App domains is 127.0.0.1 
>   Then the url to the sign up page on django is
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/user

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install django ssl server then dont access with 127.0.0.1 but use localhost  even though it will redirect you to 127.0.0.1 just use localhost:8000
Then on login to admin and on sites rename the domain name to localhost:8000
go to facebook development and add the following

- domain name = localhost 
  go to add platform on bottom of the page and add website then fill this way
- http://localhost:8000

**HOW TO INSTALL DJANGO SSLSERVER**
  https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver

HOPE IT WORKS